# How do I study the convergence of the following function sum?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

$\sum_{n\geq{0}}n!x^{n!}$   It has the form of a power series, but I don't know how to treat power series raised to a higher power than $n$ and I can't figure out a way to rewrite it so that it has the form of a regular power series. Generally my approach to power series question is to find a $c_n \in C $ such that the power series can be viewed as a $\sum_{n\geq{0}}c_nx^{n}$ and to study the convergence radius etc.. from there, but I have never encountered a question where the variable $x$ needs to be manipulated as well. Any hints or suggestions on how to tackle problems like this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Coefficient of $x^{k}$ is $0$ if $k$ is not a  factorial.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4090644/505767

Comment: Try tu use the ratio test: A real or complex sum $\sum a_n$ converges if  $lim$  $sup$ $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1$ ( if $a_n \neq 0$ for almost all n)